# Modifying TextView crashes program

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

So I've defined a layout in `xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/char_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I try to change anything about it in `java` my program crashes.

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView charName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.char_name);
    charName.setText("Bob");
    setContentView(R.layout.displayName);

    }
}
```

My app compiles and runs, but when it switches to this `Activity` it crashes.  If I set the text in the `xml` file it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set content for the *Activity*. Add the following in `onCreate`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    TextView charName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.char_name);
    charName.setText("Bob");
}
```

where `your_layout.xml` is the *xml* file containing `TextView` with *id* `char_name`.

**NOTE:** you should set content before initializing `TextView charName`.

Answer (score 0):

add The layout containing your textView to your activity:

**solution:**

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutname);
```

Answer (score 0):

change below code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displayName);

    TextView charName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.char_name);
    charName.setText("Bob");


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.displayName);

    TextView charName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.char_name);
    charName.setText("Bob");
}
```